# gtk_file_chooser_get_filename with unicode path

Tags: c, unicode, gtk

`gtk_file_chooser_get_filename` works fine with files having no unicode characters. But if I choose a file in a folder with unicode characters (japanese in my case) I don't get the correct filename.

Is there a `wchar_t` version of `gtk_file_chooser_get_filename` or should I do extra processing with the filename to get a `wchar_t` string?

```
char* filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(fileChooser);

std::cout  << filename << std::endl;
std::wcout << filename << std::endl;
```

Comment: " I don't get the correct filename." What do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gtk_file_chooser_get_filename()` returns [strings encoded with the current locale](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#id-1.3.14.6.11.5) which may or may not be UTF-8. `g_filename_to_utf8()` converts filenames from the locale encoding to UTF-8.

`std::wcout` instead expects wide chars, not UTF-8. On my system `sizeof(wchar_t)` is four bytes, so `std::wcout` expects strings encoded in UTF-32.

`std::cout << filename << std::endl;` should work fine, as no conversion is done.

For `std::wcout << filename << std::endl;` you would need to convert from your locale (which hopefully is UTF-8) to UTF-32 (or whatever your compiler uses for wide chars), for instance by using [`std::wstring_convert::from_bytes()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/from_bytes).